# RSS aggregation packages

Tags: python, django, rss, aggregate, feed

We are looking to add a news/articles section to an existing site which will be powered by aggregating content via RSS feeds. The requirements are

- Be able to aggregate lots of feeds. Initially we will start with small number of and eventually we may be aggregating few hundreds of them.
- We don't want to display the whole post on our site. We will display summary or short description and when user clicks on read more, he will be taken to the original post on external site.
- We would like to grab the image/s related to a post and display that as a small thumbnail with a post on our site.
- Create an automated tag cloud out of all the aggregated content.
- Categorize aggregated content by using category/sub-category structure.
- The aggregation piece should perform well.

Our web app is built using Django and so I am looking into selecting one the following packages. Based on our requirements, which package would you recommend?

- django-planet
- django-news
- planetplanet
- feedjack

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good idea of what you want, why not just try them all? If you have pretty strict requirements, write it yourself, roll your own aggregator with [feedparser](http://www.feedparser.org/).